# How do you extract a key value from a json array and pass it to a variable to assign to a label?

Tags: iphone, arrays, json, label

I've got an array populated with json.

```
rows4 = [dict objectForKey:@"users"];
```

I have the following line that parses a key value from it.

```
NSString *hotelname = (NSString *) [rows4 valueForKey:@"H_NAME"];
```

I then assign the value to a label in the view with the following line:

```
LabelName.Text= hotelname;
```

Everything seems fine upto here. I write the log with Nslog as follows :

```
NSLog(@"HotelName : %@",hotelname);
```

This comes up in log:

[11437:f803] HotelName : (
    "Blah Blah Hotel"
)

And then the simulator crashes with the following error in log:

> **NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

What I understand from this is the variable that I assign to the label is actually not a variable but it is an array. Am I right? If so, how can I extract a single value from my variable with the help of a key and assign it to a variable which then I can assign to a label?

I am using touchJSON btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be:

```
if(hotelname.count > 0)    
    LabelName.Text= [hotelname objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I intended to write more, but enter submitted the comment rather than moving down :)  I did not use the if statement. but LabelName.Text= [hotelname objectAtIndex:0]; did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273171/iphone-with-sbjson-framework-cant-parse-json-array). JSON is not an array, it's a dictionary.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        //below is a function from [this tutorial][2]
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithString:@"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [jsonString JSONValue];
    NSLog(@"Dictionary value for \"foo\" is \"%@\"", [dictionary objectForKey:@"foo"]);

        //This is your code, just changed some stuff...

        NSString *hotelname = (NSString *) [jsonString valueForKey:@"?"];
        LabelName.Text= hotelname;
}
```

Hope this helped, cheers.